# Can I bind a key as buffer local but not in the active keymap?

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, isearch, buffer-local, mode-specific-map

So I'm writing some custom functions to help me editing some guitar chords using LaTeX's `songs` package. I find convenient to rebind `isearch-exit`, so that when I press `RET`, the cursor is left at the beginning of the matched text (this speeds up in inserting chords in the right position). Since I do this only in some specific files, I thought to create a custom minor mode, and active that in those files using an `eval` in `.dir-locals`. The point is, I need to bind `RET` in `isearch-mode-map` (like with `define-key`), but only in a buffer local way (like with `local-set-key`). Can this be done?

Ideally, given this function:

```lisp
(defun isearch-exit-other-end ()
  "Exit isearch, at the opposite end of the string."
  (interactive)
  (goto-char isearch-other-end)
  (isearch-exit))
;; (define-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "M-<return>") #'isearch-exit-other-end)

(define-minor-mode chord-insertion-mode
  "Mode to help inserting chords with the LaTeX \"songs\" package, at the right spot."
  :lighter " chord"
  :keymap `((,(kbd "C-c C-c") . #'my--insert-chord)
        (,(kbd "C-c c") . #'my--insert-chord)
        )
  :after-hook (???)) ;; <----- WHAT TO PLACE HERE?
```

I would like to do something similar to

```lisp
(define-local-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "RET") #'isearch-exit-other-end)
```

How can I set a key **buffer-locally**, but in a keymap **different from the active one**?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple possibilities I can think of. Both involve doing everything that's conditional in a command that's bound to what `isearch-exit` is normally bound to. Either modify `isearch-exit` itself or replace it with your own command.

1. Just remap `isearch-exit` to a command you write that tests whether something is true in the current major mode.  E.g.:

   ```lisp
   (define-key [remap isearch-exit] 'my-isearch-exit)
   ```

   That "something is true" test could test a buffer local Boolean variable, or it could test whether some minor mode is enabled. You can use the mode hook for a major mode to set the local variable value or turn on the minor mode.

   In other words: just change `RET` and `<return>` to use your command, which does what you want and then does what `isearch-exit` does (or vice versa) - it can invoke `isearch-exit`.
2. Just advise `isearch-exit`, to *conditionally* do what you want before or after it does its thing. The advice would test the value of some buffer-local variable or minor mode -- see #1 above.

Comment: Overkill solution: make isearch-mode-map buffer-local, and use `copy-keymap`, then set your binding in the copy

Comment: @rpluim Can this be done without changing the code of `isearch-forward`?

Comment: I put it in as an answer, since those have nicer formatting and better permanence :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do it by making `isearch-mode-map` buffer-local:

```
(make-local-variable 'isearch-mode-map)
(setq isearch-mode-map (copy-keymap isearch-mode-map))
(define-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "RET") #'isearch-exit-other-end)
```

It's a little heavy-weight in that it ends up creating a copy of
`isearch-mode-map` for every buffer, which you could possibly avoid by
using keymap-inheritance, but I've not tested that.

Comment: Thanks! I don't get it one thing: what do you mean by "keymap-inheritance"? The possibility to have different keymaps active? Can it be done buffer-locally?

Comment: Instead of creating the keymap with `copy-keymap`, you could create it with `make-sparse-keymap` (which would be an empty keymap), define your binding in it, and then set its parent to `isearch-mode-map` using `set-keymap-parent`. That way you'd only have buffer-local versions of your almost empty keymap, rather than the whole of `isearch-mode-map`. But it's something I haven't tested, so it might not work.